# Spring Boot - Initialize mysql with .sql Script is failed

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I need an advice for running sql script when i startup with spring project.

Here's where i am :

- I **don't** want to use JPA(Hibernate) -> No JPA dependency in pom.xml
- Spring Project, mysql are running very well, But **No Data** in my DB.

looks very small issue, but can't figure out what is the problem ;(

Thanks in advance!

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.21</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDB
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root-password
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.platform=mysql
```

**schema-mysql.sql**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_db;

CREATE TABLE test_db
(
    id    int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    value VARCHAR(25),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

**data-mysql.sql**

```
INSERT INTO test_db(value) VALUES(100);
```

Comment: how do you try to execute this script?

Comment: @andrew17 I try to run db script automatically when i start spring project. I guess it is possible, isn't it ?

Comment: But where? You do it in code? Connecting by MySQL connector and using jdbc? But I dont see JDBC dependency. Using migration tools? Then I dont see migration dependency. How do you try to execute your sql script? Where it is located?

Comment: @andrew17 oh I'd like to initialize DB when i run spring application like h2 database initialization.(create schema, insert data..), not on my java code.

Comment: So after running Spring App, you connect to MySQL manually and execute sql there by yourself?

Comment: Not by myself, I think Spring Boot can initialize DB with JDBC. Reference Document : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.2/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts

Comment: Dont know what the reason to that. Better to use Flyway/Liquibase migrations for that

Answer (score 0):

Flyway example. Add to resources folder, for example 'scripts' and put your scripts. Then add property  application.properties

```
spring.flyway.user=root
spring.flyway.password=root-password
spring.flyway.schema=public
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDB
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

I failed to use the concept 'JDBC initialize'.
But thanks to the opinion @andrew17 and @K.Nikita, I decided to use Flyway.
(I'd never known flyway before, thanks again!)

So Here is the result of the configuration files.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Restagram</url>
        <user>root</user>
        <password>qwER12#$</password>
        <baselineOnMigrate>true</baselineOnMigrate>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDB
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root-password
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.platform=mysql
```

**data file(.sql)**

- location : resources/db/migration
- DDL file Name : V1__create_testDB.sql (create table query is in here)
- DML file Name : V1.1__insert_testDB.sql (insert query is in here)